# CSS same classes different behavior

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm struggling with getting my article promoting boxes to work as I want them to. The first box works as expected and I would like every box after that to work the same. However when you hover the image on any box after the first it dosn't trigger the hover class.

I think the problem lies in how the image class is selected when the box class is being hovered. I'd be gratefull for any help!

```css
.ogse-container{
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 45px;
  padding-right: 45px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0px solid #666;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px -5px #333;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.ogse-side{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #a00;
}
.ogse-img{
  position: absolute;
  height:100px;
  width: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  top: -45px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: top .2s;
}
.ogse-container:hover .ogse-img{
  top: -100px;
}


.ogse-header{
  text-align: center;
}
.ogse-para{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="ogse-container">     
  <a href="http://www.swiftpeak.net/">
       <div class="ogse-img" style="background-image: url('http://c.directlyrics.com/img/upload/example-all-the-wrong-places-artwork-cover.jpg');">
     </div>
  </a>  
  <div class="ogse-side">
  </div>
  <a href="http://www.swiftpeak.net/">
     <h2 class="ogse-header">Article header</h2>
  </a>
  <p class="ogse-para">Some sample text about, some important stuff which I can't tell anyone just yet. So i'm just going to have this text be a big mystery.</p> 
</div>
<div class="ogse-container">
  <a href="http://www.swiftpeak.net/">
       <div class="ogse-img" style="background-image: url('http://c.directlyrics.com/img/upload/example-all-the-wrong-places-artwork-cover.jpg');">
     </div>
  </a>
  <div class="ogse-side">
  </div>
  <a href="http://www.swiftpeak.net/">
     <h2 class="ogse-header">Article header</h2>
  </a>
  <p class="ogse-para">Some sample text about, some important stuff which I can't tell anyone just yet. So i'm just going to have this text be a big mystery.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Which browser are you testing in? The Snippet works for me in Chrome 53.

Comment: @bbodien I have the same browser and version. Try to hover the second box's image. That won't trigger the :hover class for the box unlike the first box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just restructured the HTML and edited the CSS a bit:

```css
.ogse-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 690px;
}
.ogse-container-inner-side {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #a00;
}
.ogse-container-inner-img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  top: -45px;
  transition: top .2s;
}
.ogse-container-inner-img div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.ogse-container:hover .ogse-container-inner-img {
  top: -100px;
}
.ogse-container-inner-text {
  margin-top: 150px;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 45px;
  padding-right: 45px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0px solid #666;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px -5px #333;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.ogse-header,
.ogse-para {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="ogse-container">
  <div class="ogse-container-inner-img">
    <a href="http://www.swiftpeak.net/">
      <div style="background-image: url('http://c.directlyrics.com/img/upload/example-all-the-wrong-places-artwork-cover.jpg');"></div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="ogse-container-inner-text">
    <div class="ogse-container-inner-side"></div>
    <a href="http://www.swiftpeak.net/">
      <h2 class="ogse-header">Article header</h2>
    </a>
    <p class="ogse-para">Some sample text about, some important stuff which I can't tell anyone just yet. So i'm just going to have this text be a big mystery.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ogse-container">
  <div class="ogse-container-inner-img">
    <a href="http://www.swiftpeak.net/">
      <div style="background-image: url('http://c.directlyrics.com/img/upload/example-all-the-wrong-places-artwork-cover.jpg');"></div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="ogse-container-inner-text">
    <div class="ogse-container-inner-side"></div>
    <a href="http://www.swiftpeak.net/">
      <h2 class="ogse-header">Article header</h2>
    </a>
    <p class="ogse-para">Some sample text about, some important stuff which I can't tell anyone just yet. So i'm just going to have this text be a big mystery.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it's flawless!

Comment: Could you also explain why this works? I.E. the cause of the OP's problem, what was it?